# How to log in automatically into several webpages through Power Shell

Tags: powershell

Dears,

This is my first time with PowerShell. Is this possible to log into several webpages via Script. So that I can run a script and I am logged into several webpages, instead of going into every one separately. This would save me a lot of time.
I searched through a web to find this but I only managed to find the code that opens a webpage.. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Maybe it would help, if you stated which browser you are using?

Comment: Google Chrome - did not know it matters

Comment: You can, but you'll need to be editing and moving cookies directly based on web calls you do with PowerShell which is an endeavor others will likely not do for you.  That being said, you can interact with Internet Explorer by creating a com object in PowerShell which will work, but won't be Chrome.

Comment: IE is also fine, I will live with IE if I have to...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is best suited for powershell, though it is possible. If you want to automate web actions then i'd suggest you look into using a library like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Most popular languages have a wrapper for selenium so you can write it in your language of choice. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/d16a390e36ec3ba54cd5e3f760cfb59e) for an example of implementing it in powershell.

Comment: I dont think my organization allow for anything different than PowerShell...I will look into it. Perhaps, anyone could provide a code in PS though.

Comment: Anyone could help with powershell script?